# Swift Split TableView in two sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I'm doing a project in Swift for my school, where I display data in a TableView. It shows information for two days, the actual day and the next day. Now I want to split the table in two Sections for each day. If it's possible with a section header with the date for each section.
How can I do that, if I already have the TableView with the data.
Best regards. ;)

```
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {

    thisName = elementName

}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "element" {
        var myPlan = Plan()
        myPlan.klasse = planKlasse
        myPlan.raum = planRaum
        myPlan.vertreter = planVertreter
        myPlan.art = planArt
        myPlan.fach = planFach
        myPlan.stunde = planStunde
        myPlan.lehrer = planLehrer
        myPlan.datum = planDatum

        print(myPlan)
        tableViewDataSource.append(myPlan)


    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {


    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if data.count != 0 {
        switch thisName {
        case "klasse": planKlasse = data
        case "vertreter": planVertreter = data
        case "raum": if data.hasPrefix("SN") { planRaum = "SNÜRN" } else {planRaum = data}
        case "art": planArt = data
        case "fach": planFach = data
        case "stunde": planStunde = data
        case "lehrer": planLehrer = data; if (data.isEmpty) { planLehrer = "-"}
        case "datum": planDatum = data
        default:
            break
        }

    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
    print("failure error: ", parseError)
}







func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {
        return filteredElements.count
    } else {
        return tableViewDataSource.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseCell", for: indexPath)

    var element: Plan

    if (searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {
        element = filteredElements[indexPath.row]
        myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    } else {
        element = tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row]
        myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    let myKlasseLabel = myCell.viewWithTag(11) as! UILabel
    let myVertreterLabel = myCell.viewWithTag(12) as! UILabel
    let myRaumLabel = myCell.viewWithTag(13) as! UILabel
    let myArtLabel = myCell.viewWithTag(15) as! UILabel
    let myFachLabel = myCell.viewWithTag(14) as! UILabel
    let myStundeLabel = myCell.viewWithTag(16) as! UILabel
    let myLehrerLabel = myCell.viewWithTag(17) as! UILabel
    let myDatumLabel = myCell.viewWithTag(18) as! UILabel


    myKlasseLabel.text = element.klasse
    myVertreterLabel.text = element.vertreter
    myRaumLabel.text = element.raum
    myArtLabel.text = element.art
    myFachLabel.text = element.fach
    myStundeLabel.text = element.stunde + "."
    myLehrerLabel.text = "(" + element.lehrer + ")"
    myDatumLabel.text = element.datum


    if (element.art == "Klausur") {
        myFachLabel.text = "-"
        myLehrerLabel.text = "-"
    }

    if ((defaults.object(forKey: "klasseWahlDef")) as? String != nil) {

        if (tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].klasse == (defaults.object(forKey: "klasseWahlDef")) as? String) {
        myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        } else if (tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].vertreter == (defaults.object(forKey: "LehrerDef")) as? String) {
           myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        }
    }

    if tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].datum != "hi" {

        let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterPrint.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
        dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "E dd.MM.yyyy"


        if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: element.datum){
            //print(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date))
            myDatumLabel.text = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)
        }
        else {
            print("There was an error decoding the string")
        }
    }
    return myCell

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share us your code for the data source?

Comment: I would share the code, but it contains a lot of personal data of the school, thats the problem. I just have one table where I show data that I parsed from XML. Row for row it enters information in labels.

Comment: I am not asking for school data. I’m asking for the code that you wrote. I don’t believe that’ll have any references to personal information.

Comment: I added the code at the top. Thats all for the parsing and the tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking code - https://github.com/RockinGarg/Expandable-TableView-.git

**Required Code**

```
//setting number of Sections
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return section.count
}
```

If you want to customise headerView

```
//Setting Header Customised View
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    //Declare cell
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as! TableViewCell

    //Setting Header Components
    headerCell.titleLabel.text = self.section[section]
    headerCell.ButtonToShowHide.tag = section

    //Handling Button Title
    if self.collapaseHandlerArray.contains(self.section[section]){
        //if its opened
        headerCell.ButtonToShowHide.setTitle("Hide", for: .normal)
    }
    else{
        //if closed
        headerCell.ButtonToShowHide.setTitle("Show", for: .normal)
    }

    //Adding a target to button
    headerCell.ButtonToShowHide.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.HandleheaderButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return headerCell.contentView

 }
```

Number Of Rows

```
//Setting number of rows in a section
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.collapaseHandlerArray.contains(self.section[section]){
        return items[section].count
    }
    else{
        return 0
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define numbers of sections you want to display:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 2
}
```

Then you have to define number of rows you want to display in every section:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        //return number of rows in first section
    }
    else {
        //return number of rows in second section
    }
}
```

If you want to create custom header, then you can use this function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // return custom header view
}
```

However, if you want to only display text in a header, you can use the default one and use only **titleForHeaderInSection** function.

Of course, you also have to return proper view for cell. If you want to check the section number, you can simply call

```
indexPath.section
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this func present in UITableViewDataSource:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return yourDateString
}
```

Comment: I think I tried this, but I need to split the table for the two dates, like today and tomorrow.

Comment: You need to split your tableViewDataSource into two parts on the bases of the dates, then in numberOfSections, just return 2, and in titleForHeaderInSection, check for section, if (section == 0), your title will be "Today" and similarly for (section == 1) your title will be "Tomorrow" and for numberOfRowsInSection return count according to your tableViewDataSource.